Similar contractions
Let $T_1:\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_1$ and $T_2:\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathcal{H}_2$ two contractions on Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, i.e. bounded linear operators with (operator) norm at most $1$.
Suppose that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar, this is $T_1=C^{-1}T_2C$ for some isomorphism $C:\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2$.
Is it true that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are unitarily similar. In order words, does there exists a unitary operator $U:\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2$ such that $T_1=U^{-1}T_2U$?

If there's a problem with the question, please let me know. Otherwise it's impossible to know.

This is nowhere near research level. The knowledge needed to construct a counterexample is just basic linear algebra. The concepts mentioned are just elementary functional analysis - and even that is because of the artificial requirements that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are contractions, which can be easily removed by just noting you can divide by the maximum of the two operator norms. If this were on Math StackExchange, I would have upvoted, but I downvoted here.

I understand. It's worth noting though that sometime trivial tricks or observations lead to significant advances. Criticizing without explanation, is the contrary to how a research community should work -unless of course one thinks science is done by competition instead of cooperation.

That is exactly why I explained my downvote. And while I of course agree that trivial tricks can be significant in research (and I’ve made those kinds of trivial observations in my own research from time to time), and while you may disagree with my take, I find this too trivial to justify calling it research-level, especially given that you didn’t provide any context to link this to any specific research topic. As is, this just boils down to finding two matrices that are similar but not unitarily conjugate, which can easily be an exercise problem for an advanced linear algebra course.

I’ve asked quite trivial questions on MathOverflow before and gotten downvoted. I find it a fair practice given that this is a research-level forum, as opposed to a general-level forum like Math StackExchange.

What if $\mathcal H_1=\mathcal H_2=\mathbb C^2$ and
$$\begin{align*}
T_1&=\begin{pmatrix}
0.1&0.05\\
&0.1
\end{pmatrix}\\
T_2&=\begin{pmatrix}
0.1&0.1\\
&0.1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}$$
Then they are similar under the matrix
$$C=\begin{pmatrix}2\\
&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Any matrix $U$ such that $T_1=U^{-1}U_2T$ must be of the form
$U=\begin{pmatrix}2a&b\\
&a\end{pmatrix}$
for some $a\in\mathbb C^\times$ and $b\in\mathbb C$. But such matrices are never unitary.

$T_2$ is not a contraction in your example as $T_2(0,1)=(1,1/2)$ has norm larger than 1.

@pipenauss maybe now it works?
